# Ansible: Unable to access nested variable in group_vars file

Tags: debugging, ansible, yaml

I have the following playbook where I am testing the access to values in my group_vars file. The first  Task run fine, but the second one is failing.  I thought that was the correct syntax to access  nested data from a vars file.

```
Failure message:
TASK [call 60 env FEX 141 uplink port from group_vars] ****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [S70G1MS001]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.  The error was: 'float object' has no attribute 'uplink'
```

I have the following data structure in my group_vars file:

```
60:
 141:
   uplink: Eth1/6
   description: "FEX101@AA33"
IZ2:
 SW1: S70G1MS001
 SW2: S70G2MS002
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: S70G1MS001
no_log: false
gather_facts: false
tasks:
  - name:  call IZ2 switch 2 from  group_vars
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ IZ2.SW2 }}"
  - name:  call 60 env FEX 141 uplink port from group_vars
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ 60.141.uplink }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I was not able to use numbers in my group_vars file to signify objects in the array. We use a numberical system to identify our various test environments, so I wanted to use those in my group_vars file.

Had to do it like this:

```
TEST:
  191:
    uplink: Eth1/24
    description: "FEX101@AA33"
```